# Getting iterators within TBB parallel_for loop

Tags: c++, iterator, c++14, tbb

I am having issues with a conceptually straightforward code. I need to collect some iterators from a vector inside a loop, and I would like to use TBB capabilities to parallelize this loop. Here a minimal (not) working example:

```
#include <tbb/tbb.h>

#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    tbb::concurrent_vector<decltype(v)::iterator> cv;
    tbb::parallel_for(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&](const auto& iter)
    {
        cv.emplace_back(iter);
    });
}
```

As you can see, I am interested in the iterators, not the values. I could accomplish a similar thing using pointers or reference wrappers (here an example below), but I would like to understand the reason I am not able to do what I want...

```
#include <tbb/tbb.h>

#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
    tbb::concurrent_vector<std::reference_wrapper<decltype(v)::value_type>> cv;
    tbb::parallel_for_each(std::begin(v), std::end(v), [&](auto& element)
    {
        cv.emplace_back(std::ref(element));
    });
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to use the following `parallel_for` overload:

```
template <typename Index, typename Function>
void parallel_for(Index first, Index last, const Function& f);
```

This overload takes two indexes to specify the block range. The `Index` type must be converted to integers, so that in the function body, i.e. the lambda you specified, you can use `v[index]` to access (index) the elements of the vector.

However, you passed iterators to this overload and the compiler couldn't convert these iterators to integers, so you got the error.

The solution is as follows:

```
tbb::parallel_for(static_cast<std::size_t>(0), v.size(), // use index to specify the range
    [&](std::size_t index) {
        cv.emplace_back(v.begin() + index);  // access element with v[index]
    });
```

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right. Inside the documentation i missed the point: 'The index type must be an integral type'. Honestly, I am not able to understand the reason behind this limitation. A random accessible iterator is able to "combine" with an integral type, it supports std::less and so on... However, thanks!